# Passar variável PHP no onclick="history.go(-1)"

Tags: php, html5, formulário, onclick

Estou tentando criar um botão que retorna ao formulário para corrigi-lo, desta forma mantendo todo o conteúdo digitado no *HTML* para que o usuário corrija a informação errada, porém enviando uma variável *PHP* para que eu possa fazer o *UPDATE* no *MySQL*, sem inserir um novo cadastro.
Pensei em enviar um `ID`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>          
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" formaction="cancela_cadastro.php" 
               value="Cancelar pedido">
        <input type="submit" formaction="../index.php" value="novo pedido">
        <input type="button" value="Corrigir" 
            onClick="(history.go(-1), '<?php echo $ID; ?>')"/>
    </form>
```

porém sem sucesso. O `ID` é inserido no `"cancela_cadastro.php?ID=XX"` e no `"../index.php?ID=XX"` - este último sem querer, mas não faz diferença.
Gostaria de saber se há como enviar essa variável no `history.go(-1)`, ou se há como enviar essa variável no retorno ao formulário preenchido.

<sub>**PS**. O `history.go(-1)` parou de funcionar quando atribuí essa variável *PHP*.</sub>

Comment: se voce quer que ele volte porque não valida o formulário ?

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, acho que tive uma idéia com ela . Ao invés de retornar à submissão, eu mostro os campos preenchidos e peço para o usuário corrigir ou realmente enviar o formulário... Claro! Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Só pra complementar, não é possível passar outros parâmetros no método `go()` do `window.history`. Ele só aceita um `int` ou uma `string` contendo uma URL.

Comment: Obrigada pelas respostas. Acho que ficarei com um formulário "intermediário", entre o de envio e o de confirmação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de fazer `history.go(-1)` crie uma função onde você passa o ID e redireciona ele para a pagina que precisa por exemplo:

```
<script>
function redirect(id){

    window.location.href = 'suapagina.php?id='+id;

}
</script>
```

Caso queira da para adicionar o parâmetro page no método, para que você reutilize em outros lugares se necessário.

Comment: Vou testar aqui. Obrigada pela resposta!

Comment: De nada, se for útil e puder votar e aceitar agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de:

```
<input type="button" value="Corrigir" onClick="(history.go(-1), '<?php echo $ID; ?>')">
```

Sugiro:

```
<input type="button" value="Corrigir" onClick="parent.location.href='pagina_destino.php?id=<?php echo $ID; ?>'">
```

Comment: Testei a sua sugestão, porém o formulário original voltou em branco. Gostaria de passar o "ID" mantendo o que foi digitado anteriormente, mas ou menos como o botão "voltar" do navegador.

Comment: Na tela anterior os arquivos não foram salvos no banco de dados?